# How change RadDataFilter Filter Options style

Tags: silverlight, telerik, styles

I have a Silverlight application which has a RadDataFilter.

I want to change the size of FilterEdit (TextBox which we write the filter parameter) and also I want to hide MatchCase button when I have filter definition of type string!

How would I start to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please provide some code example?

Answer (score 0):

In the EditorCreated event of RadDataFilter, when I changed the "e.Editor.Width" the size of TextBox changed!

Comment: The last part of my question is not solved! I want to hide MatchCase button of RadDataFilter!